# how to implement WHERE IN function in SQL using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can i implement where in query using codeigniter,when am using 
$this->db->where_in function means it takes only first value of my input array and it will exit.I need to check with multiple values of an input

Comment: Show us your code. We can't help you just with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controller code

```
$where[]=array("your_field_name IN (1,2,3) ");
```

and pass this array to your_method in model as i shown you below

model code

```
function your_method($where)
    {
      $this->db->select('your table.*');
        if(!empty($where))
        {
            foreach ($where as $key => $value)
            {
                if(is_array($value))
                    $this->db->where($value[0], '', false);
                else
                    $this->db->where($key, $value);
            }
        }
        $q = $this->db->get('your_sql_table');

        if($q->num_rows() > 0)
            return $q->result_array();
        else
            return null;
    }
```